# Webpack source map weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, webpack

I came across a strange behaviour of Webpack (4.35.2), calling my function twice when `devtool: "source-map"`.

Here's a simple structure to replicate:

**index.js**

```
(function test() {
    console.log("function test");
})();
```

**other.js**

```
import t from "./index";
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./index.js",
        other: "./other.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ],

    devtool: "source-map",

    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true
    }
};
```

If you run it, `test()` gets called twice.
Then change the `devtool` to something else and it gets called once (as I think it should).

Does anyone know what's happening?